# Saving Voicemails from my iPhone 6s

Tags: iphone, voicemail

I have Voicemails on my iPhone 6s from my mother who recently passed.  Please advise the best way for me to save these.

Comment: I am sorry to hear about your loss. Have you tried "iMazing"?

Answer (score 2):

One fairly straight forward way of doing this is to grab another iPhone / iPod Touch / iPad and use the Voice Memos app to record them while they're playing on your iPhone on speaker.

Once you've recorded them you can Share them from the Voice Memos app by sending them via email to yourself or using one of the  other options.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) to get the Voicemail from both my iPhone and backups made in iTunes of my iPhone, to have separate copies of all the Voicemails. They can then be played right in Finder in Icon view, just click the file, or played in QuickTime Player, which is the default for files with the *.arm* extension which the Voicemails have.

[image]